# Is magsafe 2 charger somehow associated with a Macbook by serial?

Tags: macbook-pro, magsafe

My Magsafe2 charger just broke down. We have 2 Macbook Pros in house, and I can't be sure which is which. If it's my charger, I'll have to buy a new one. If it belongs to the other macbook - it should be still covered with Warranty.

Is there a way to check if a charger belongs to a specific Macbook? Both chargers are model A1424 85W. Both laptops are Macbook Retina Pro, both year 2013 ( one early, the other late ).

Answer (score 3):

No. There is no serialization on chargers. If so, the 350 Mac laptops in many carts all over our campuses wouldn't charge because students (and some faculty) seem unable to read numbered slots and match the numbers on the laptops. Don't worry.